# Is it faster to insert inline HTML or create a new element?

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

I have a question, I use prototype, but maybe this question could apply to native javascript as well.

Which would be generally faster and more efficient to run:

```
$(divElement).insert('<div>Hello</div');
```

or

```
$(divElement).insert(new Element(div).insert('Hello'));
```

How about creating the element seperatly and assigning it to a variable like this:

```
var helloDiv = '<div>Hello</div>';
$(divElement).insert(helloDiv);
```

or

```
var helloDiv = new Element('div').insert('Hello');
$(divElement).insert(helloDiv);
```

Is creating inline html faster than creating an element and then inserting it? This information could be useful especially for constructing something like tables.

Thank you and appreciate your help.

Comment: You should accept some of the answers to your old questions. You can find them by viewing your profile. It is how SO works

Comment: I don't think the speed is an issue here. Both are lightning fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the browser, its definitely true for ie and firefox but seems slower on chrome:
http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-createelement-test.

Comment: Note that your test works poorly for direct DOM manipulation, because you used innerHTML anyway. [This](http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-createelement-test/2)  minor improvement increases speed by a factor of 2 in Firefox.Still slower than innerHTML there though.

Answer (score 2):

`innerHTM`L is faster than `appendChild`

The advantage of `appendChild` is that it actually updates the DOM properly in all browsers so that you can actually read back and update the tags you added.

Using `innerHTML` does not update the DOM in all browsers and so the content added that way may not be able to be updated after it is added (if you need to do that).